# Why isn't the following regex removing the ## characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
  for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; ++i) {
    if (tree[i].match(/^##/g)) {
      console.log(tree[i])
      tree[i] = '<p><a href="#toc-' + tocIndex++ + '">' +
        tree[i].replace('/^## /gm', '') +
      '</a></p>'
      console.log(tree[i])
      tocItems.push(tree[i])
    }
  }
```

The first `console.log(tree[i])` outputs `## Chapter 1` The second one outputs:

```
<p><a href="#toc-1">## Chapter 1</a></p>
```

But it should output instead:

```
<p><a href="#toc-1">Chapter 1</a></p>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the array (?) "tree" contain?

Comment: Your `replace` regex has been put in quotes. This is a typo question. Close-voting.

Comment: I recommend http://regexper.com/ for trying out regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't use regex correctly search google on how to use regex in javascript to learn that. btw you don't need regex to do that. here is the fix:

```
 tree[i].replace('##', '') + '</a></p>'
```